# How to choose padding for vertical rhythm

Tags: html, css

I have a very fundamental question to choose padding size for vertical rhythm.

Let's say that:

```
.body{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

And we have a div with content (div has a border):

```
<div class="content">
     ... a very large text content here ...
</div>
```

Which one of the following would be the right chose for vertical align, this one:

```
.content{ padding: 18px; .... }
```

or should I consider the difference (18-14)/2 = 2px, So:

```
.content{ padding: 16px 18px 16px 18px;  .... }
```

or if both answers are wrong, would you please explain how to approach this issue.

Comment: I guess, padding-top should be = 2 x line-height & padding-bottom should be = line-height

Answer (score 0):

You should set the same padding on top and the bottom of the container. example:

```
.content {
padding: 10px 0;
line-height: 14px;
}
<div class="content">
 ...some text here...
</div>
```

Also you can set the height of the div and then set the same line-height